# Differentiating $(e^x+1)/x$ at $x=1$ according to the definition of differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I tried the following:

```
f'(1)=lim(((e^x+1)/x -(e+1))/x-1) when x=1 and get the result 0/0
```

I have tried to do a lot of approaches and get the same result (0/0).

but I can't find the derive of  (e^x+1)/x when x=1 according to the definition

I have tried it using the popular rules:

```
f'(x)=(e^x*x - e^x +1)/x^2
```

and then

```
f'(1)=(e*1-e-1)/1^2 = -1
```

How can I get the same result using the definition?

Comment: Good grief, this isn't rocket science. I corrected the title.

Comment: @MPW You're right; we were trying only to help the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one wishes to use brute force, and not rely on established theorems from differential calculus, then one can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left.\left(\frac{e^x+1}{x}\right)\right|_{x=1}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{e^{1+h}+1}{1+h}-(e+1)}{h}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{1+h}-(1+h)e-h}{h(1+h)}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, we use the elementary inequalities that can be obtained (without calculus)

$$1+h \le e^h\le\frac{1}{1-h}$$

to reveal that

$$-\frac{1}{1+h} \le \frac{e^{1+h}-(1+h)e-h}{h(1+h)}\le \frac{eh}{1-h^2}-\frac{1}{1+h}$$

Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, we have the expected result that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{e^{1+h}+1}{1+h}-(e+1)}{h}\right)=-1$$

And we are done!